# Python mixin with a method that cannot be overridden (by default)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python, I am using a framework that lets me hook into a lifecycle like so:

```
class MyView(BaseView):
    def pre_save(self):
        print "view presave"
```

I want to write a mixin to do something in `pre_save`, but I already have lots of code in lots of classes using `pre_save` as above, without calling `super()`.  If I add in my mixin like so:

```
class MyMixin(object):
    def pre_save(self):
        print "mixin presave"

class MyView(MyMixin, BaseView):
    def pre_save(self):
        print "view presave"
```

It naturally overwrites the mixin, and prints "view presave" only.  Is there another, sneakier way I can write `MyMixin` to not force all client views to remember to call `super()`?

Comment: No, there is no other way but to call `super()` from all your `pre_save()` methods. If `BaseView.pre_save()` exists (and does nothing, not even call `super()`) then using `super()` everywhere (mixin, concrete views) will ensure all calls are properly chained.

Comment: Piling "sneakier ways" over plain programming mistakes will only add some kludge to something that ought to be fixed.  Fix you views so they properly issue the `super` call, it will save you much more time in the long run.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I don't think "plain programming mistakes" is accurate - there was no mixin before so no need to call `super()`, and one shouldn't need to know how the mixin is implemented to take advantage of it.  As is, you can unwittingly knock out your mixin's implementation with no warning.

Comment: @ScottStafford yes was a bit harsh sorry - but I maintain that not calling on `super.pre_save()` in the views was a mistake from the start as it obviously would break both adding code in `BaseView.pre_save` and adding mixins or intermediate classes in the call chain. As you say, "one shouldn't need to know how" all this is implemented, and your mistake comes from the fact you "knew" at some point "there was no need to call super()". TL;DR : not calling on `super` when you override a method is a mistake even if the base method is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a proof of concept, not a recommendation.  **DO NOT DO THIS IN PRODUCTION CODE.**  You will create maintenance nightmare.  I agree with those commenting on your question that the only safe approach is editing the derived classes.

That said, it is technically possible using a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation).

```
def do_evil(self, method):
    print "doing evil"
    MyMixin.pre_save(self)
    method(self)

class ConcentratedEvil(type):
    tainted_classes = ['MyView'] # Add others as needed
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dict):
        if name in mcs.tainted_classes:
            print "tainting {0} with the power of evil".format(name)
            old_method = dict['pre_save']
            dict['pre_save'] = lambda x: do_evil(x, old_method)
            print dict.keys()
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, dict)

class BaseView(object):
    pass

class MyMixin(object):
    __metaclass__ = ConcentratedEvil
    def pre_save(self):
        print "mixin presave"

class MyView(MyMixin, BaseView):
    def pre_save(self):
        print "view presave"
```

At which point you can do:

```
>>> view = MyView()
>>> view.pre_save()
doing evil
mixin presave
view presave
>>>
```

I think this only works if MyMixin is at the front of the base class list.

Comment: Neato. Think I can automatically taint all classes that use `MyMixin`, rather than maintaining the `tainted_classes` list?

Comment: Hmm.  Probably.  I bet you could search the bases list for "MyMixin".  I'm not sure how it would work if your classes are in different modules.  You might have to check for both the qualified and unqualified names.